# Salesforce Data Extensions not available for Contact Builder Data Model

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, contactbuilder, data-model

Why are data extensions in Salesforce Data Extension folder/sub-folder not available to be added in the contact builder data model? Is this a very specific design restriction? To the best of my understanding having data extensions in the Salesforce data extension folder only serves as a directory that can enable tracking to be sent back to Salesforce when sends are made through Email/Automation studio. Why is this folder not available when building contact builder data model? Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: In a sense, they are available. Go to Synchronized Data Extensions under the Data Sources Tab and you should see them listed. They are already synced up. I'm not sure, but I imagine this is why they are you can't set up your own relationships with them. And I haven't tried it, but you should be able to link to these in an attribute group as well.

Comment: @garek007 - you are mixing Salesforce Data Extensions with Synchronised Data Extensions. The latter are indeed available in Contact Builder, but are not the ones mentioned in the original post.

Comment: @LukasLunow you are right, I must have misinterpreted what the OP was asking. my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce Data Extensions are indeed not available in Contact Builder - only in Email Studio. This is a limitation of the application, you are not missing anything. I normally set up the entire contact model in Data Designer using regular data extensions, and only use the Salesforce Data Extensions for e.g. Guided Sends. Remember, the contact model is mainly utilised in Journey Builder, which always will push tracking back to Sales Cloud, regardless what type of Data Extension is being used as entry event.

Comment: thanks @lukas! That is what I thought as well, but wanted to check. The ask here was to simply use a certain segment which is already part of Contact Builder Data Model for certain (adhoc) sends. I think the same can be achieved using a DE populated with a query or (may be) a filtered DE.